# How do we convert a column from table to an arraylist using ormlite?

Tags: ormlite

I'm trying to convert an entire column values into a arrayList using ormlite on android, is this possible, with direct api?
Using raw results i get close, but not quite:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
     getHelper().getMyProcessDao().queryRaw(
         queryBuild.selectColumns("nid").prepareStatementString());
List<String[]> result = rawResults.getResults();
```

Comment: I've been adding accept rating to my latest questions. Didnt know it was really important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hrm.  I'm not sure this is what you want.  However, one way to accomplish what you ask for specifically is through by using the [`RawRowMapper`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapper.html) which can be passed to [ORMLite's](http://ormlite.com/) DAO method: [dao.queryRaw(String, Rowmapper, String...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowMapper,%20java.lang.String...%29).

Something like the following should work:

```
RawRowMapper<Integer> mapper = new RawRowMapper<Integer>() {
     public Integer mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) {
        // maybe you should verify that there _is_ only 1 column here
        // maybe you should handle the possibility of a bad number and throw
        return Integer.parseInt(resultColumns[0]);
     }
};
GenericRawResults<Integer> rawResults =
    getHelper().getMyProcessDao().queryRaw(
        queryBuild.selectColumns("nid").prepareStatementString(), mapper);
List<Integer> list = rawResults.getResults();
```